# Call function after minimum time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a spinner while waiting for Ajax request.
The request time is really random. Some time It takes more than 2 seconds. Which is fine as the user can see the spinner. 
The problem is when the request takes few hundreds of milliseconds. User can not see the spinner as it was displayed and hidden two quickly.

I was thinking about calling Ajax request from `setTimeout` with 2 seconds. But that's not a good idea as if Ajax request takes 3 seconds, for example, the spinner will be displayed for 5 seconds instead of 3.

How can I achieve this scenario:

1. Hide the spinner after 2 seconds, if the Ajax request takes less then 2 seconds
2. Hide the spinner after Ajax request is done, if Ajax request takes more than 2 seconds

Comment: Any code you would like to share?

Comment: Why do you want to add an artificial delay? Surely no delay ( hence no spinner) is preferable?

Comment: I would like to let the user know that I'm working on his request. Just a feedback to the user

Comment: @Mhd: I've done this (though I think only for about a second), so the user doesn't get a weird random flash (the spinner) they don't have time to properly see or understand before it's gone.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's exactly what I need it for

Comment: @Mhd: IIRC, I also combined it with *not* showing the spinner for 250ms because in my scenario frequently the ajax finished in that time and that's just about the outside edge of how long someone is okay with waiting without seeing feedback. So if the ajax finished in <250ms, no spinner at all and the user sees a near-instantaneous result. But if >=250ms, I left the spinner up long enough for them to process it.

Comment: Are you asking this from a technical perspective?  If you are, you need to show code and change your question to say what your problem in implementing is.  If you are asking "What amount of time warrants a spinner?", you should ask on the UX Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with promises.

```
var timer_deferred = $.Deferred();
var ajax = $.ajax( {
    url : '/echo/html'
} );

setTimeout( function(){ timer_deferred.resolve() }, 2000 );

$.when( timer_deferred, ajax ).done( function(){
    alert( 'Hide Spinner' );
} );
```

`when` will wait until both promises are completed. So if the `ajax` call is finishing first, it will still wait 2 seconds.

I also suggest that instead of waiting 2 seconds, you should add an indicator that the AJAX is done.

---

### Here an alternative using native Promise objects (thanks to [T.J Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder))

For recent browser (not I.E), you can use native promise as well for better performances.

```
var timer_promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
});

var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : '/echo/html'
});

Promise.all([timer_promise, ajax]).then(function(){
    alert( 'Hide Spinner' );
});
```

Comment: Oh, I like that. It's still using flags, like mine, they're just in the promises -- and thus composable, etc. (In fact, the last time I had to do this, I think I did...this.) Probably worth showing the native Promise version.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not used to the native Promise version *yet*. I know! Lack of will I guess... Would it be used like this (https://jsfiddle.net/69g14Lco/) or am I missing something?

Comment: That works, but I'd use `Promise.all` and if you like, you can pass `resolve` into `setTimeout` directly: https://jsfiddle.net/69g14Lco/2/

Comment: Well, that looks good. Great idea to pass the resolve as `setTimeout` callback, witty. I bet we could use `XMLHttpRequest` as a promise as well, right? I will keep `$.ajax` in the example since it's simpler.

Comment: :-) We could by using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), yeah. But it's a jQuery question, no need for us to go too far astray... (And there was nothing wrong with your original pure-jQuery answer at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this exact thing. :-)

The way I did it was along these lines (pseudocode):

```
var runningLong = false;
var ajaxComplete = false;
setTimeout(function() {
    if (ajaxComplete) {
        // Stop spinning
        spinning = false;
    } else {
        runningLong = true;
    }
}, 2000);
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        ajaxComplete = true;
        if (runningLong) {
            // Stop spinning
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 2 seconds was just example. Ajax can take 2 or 3 depending upon load on backend server. So hard coded timeout with 2000 will not work.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: I suggest re-reading the question (and, for that matter, the answer). The OP clearly says that if the ajax takes fewer than two seconds, they want the spinner to keep spinning for the full two seconds. But if it runs longer, they want it to keep spinning longer. That's what the above does.

Comment: Ohk. got it. Your are right. I am taking back my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use this (my loader is pure css), I think that it's a very good solution for you :

```
    //loader start
    $('#loader').delay(100).fadeIn(800);

    $.ajax('/ajax',{    
        ...
    }).fail(function(xhr,txt,e){
       ...
    }).always(function(){
        //loader stop and hide on ajax callback (success or error)
        $('#loader').stop(true,true).hide();
    });
```

You can ajust the two values (100 and 800) (start to display after 100ms, if faster than 100ms never show, fade from 0% to 100% opacity between 100ms 900ms, and alway hide after the request completed (even if it fails).
Don't show a loader if it's very fast.
Adding a fade is great instead of poping up a loader somewhere !

#loader is a centered position:absolute div id="loader" with a css loader in my projet, but you can put it where you want.

Nice css loaders :

http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

https://codepen.io/collection/HtAne/

Comment: While delaying it is a good suggestion (one I made in a comment, in fact), this doesn't answer the OP's question -- it removes the spinner/loader as soon as the ajax call completes, even if that's only one second later.